# Render does not work after call to update function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller's update function looks like this:

```
def update
    @cohort = Cohort.find(params[:cohort][:id])
    @cohort.update_attributes(params[:cohort])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render action: "show", layout: "courses"}
    end
end
```

When I trigger the `update` function (via js), get the following in my Rails console:

```
Started PUT "/cohorts/41" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-18 21:57:26 -0400
Processing by CohortsController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"cohort"=>{"id"=>"41", "user_id"=>"17", "room_id"=>"16"}, "id"=>"41"}
  Cohort Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "cohorts".* FROM "cohorts" WHERE "cohorts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "41"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "cohorts" SET "room_id" = 16, "updated_at" = '2014-07-18 21:57:26.303928' WHERE "cohorts"."id" = 41
   (8.5ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 17 LIMIT 1
  Course Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."id" = 21 LIMIT 1
  Timeperiod Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "timeperiods".* FROM "timeperiods" WHERE "timeperiods"."id" = 37 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 17 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (role = 'faculty' OR role = 'admin')
  FacultyReport Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "faculty_reports".* FROM "faculty_reports" WHERE "faculty_reports"."cohort_id" = 41 LIMIT 1
  Room Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" 
  Room Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" = 16 LIMIT 1
  Enrollment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "enrollments".* FROM "enrollments" WHERE "enrollments"."cohort_id" = 41
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 17 LIMIT 1
  Rendered cohorts/show.html.erb within layouts/courses (12.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_leftnav.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44.7ms (Views: 31.1ms | ActiveRecord: 10.0ms)
```

Notice it says `Rendered cohorts/show.html.erb within layouts/courses (12.3ms)`.  In the browser itself, no refresh or re-rendering occurs.  If I manually refresh the page, I can see the changes were made but the page itself change.

Also, if I change `render` to `redirect_to` I get (in the console) a redirect loop that goes for about 14 iterations and then stops and no changes in the browser.

Comment: Refer rails guide for rendering action view http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: you are calling your update method by ajax?

Comment: @Addicted, I've been to that page and it seems I'm using a format they specify.  If something looks incorrect to you, would you tell me what it is?

Comment: @EricBaldwin if it's js request then why are you using html format in controller?

Comment: If you make an AJAX request there will be no automatic refresh of the current page or its content. You must handle the response from the server (with JavaScript code) and make the changes you desire (updating content, etc).

Comment: I changed `format.js {render action: "show", layout: "courses"}` to `format.js {render "update.js.erb"}` and it works as intended. Anyone can feel free to submit this answer for a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**respond_to**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to)

From your comments & looking at your code, you need to remember how Rails `repond_to` block works

When you call `format.js`, Rails will automatically look for `[action_name].js.erb` in your `views/controller` folder. This file will essentially run when you hit the `update` action from ajax / JS, it will perform the function & then look for `update.js.erb` to run.

You have several issues with your code:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
    def update
        @cohort = Cohort.find(params[:cohort][:id])
        @cohort.update_attributes(params[:cohort])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js {render layout: "courses"} #-> automatically loads views/your_controller/update.js.erb
        end
    end
end
```

--

**Update**

Something else you should consider is your `update` functionality - specifically that you're trying to update a model with naked `params` (you should use [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)):

```
def update
    @cohort = Cohort.find params[:cohort][:id]
    @cohort.update(cohort_params)
end  

private

def cohort_params
    params.require(:cohort).permit(:your, :params)
end
```

Edit:

I changed `format.js {render action: "show", layout: "courses"}` to `format.js {render "update.js.erb"}` and it works as intended.